# Unable to get DeliverToCompID (Tag128) value on acceptor application in QuickFix/J

Tags: validation, quickfixj

I am trying to make the DeliverToCompID (tag128) mandatory on NewOrderSingle Message. I am able to send the message from Banzai with tag128 present, but still getting this --> `58=Required tag missing371=128`   error message.

I have declared the DeliverToCompID (tag128) value in the config file

```
[session]
SocketConnectPort=9878
DeliverToCompID=FIXIMULATOR3
SenderCompID=BANZAI
TargetCompID=FIXIMULATOR
```

and in Banzai Application I am fetching the value from the config and setting it in the message.

```
String tag128 = settings.getString(sessionID,"DeliverToCompID");
System.out.println("tag 128  "+tag128);
message.getHeader().setField(new DeliverToCompID(tag128));
```

and I am sending a NewOrderSingle Message, and TAG 128 is present in the logs of both the banzai(sender) and fiximulator(acceptor) application.

**BANZAI LOG** <20221111-05:28:39, FIX.4.2:BANZAI->FIXIMULATOR, outgoing> (8=FIX.4.29=15435=D34=749=BANZAI52=20221111-05:28:39.66056=FIXIMULATOR**128=FIXIMULATOR3**11=166814451964721=138=256340=154=155=AAA59=060=20221111-05:28:39.65810=238)

**FIXIMULATOR LOG** <20221111-05:28:39, FIX.4.2:FIXIMULATOR->BANZAI, incoming> (8=FIX.4.29=15435=D34=749=BANZAI52=20221111-05:28:39.66056=FIXIMULATOR128=FIXIMULATOR311=166814451964721=138=256340=154=155=AAA59=060=20221111-05:28:39.65810=238)

But I am getting this ::  <20221111-05:28:39, FIX.4.2:FIXIMULATOR->BANZAI, event> (Message 7 Rejected: Required tag missing:128)
<20221111-05:28:39, FIX.4.2:FIXIMULATOR->BANZAI, outgoing> (8=FIX.4.29=12635=334=749=FIXIMULATOR52=20221111-05:28:39.66456=BANZAI115=FIXIMULATOR345=758=Required tag missing371=128372=D373=110=084)

I have used custom FIX42.xml file

```
 <message name="NewOrderSingle" msgtype="D" msgcat="app">
     
      <field name="DeliverToCompID" required="Y"/>
```

and in the FIXIMLATOR config  I have made

```
ValidateIncomingMessage=Y
DataDictionary=config/FIX42.xml
UseDataDictionary=Y
```

Comment: The field is from the header. If you add it in the message body the parser will complain that it's not present.

Just change the header field to be mandatory

<fix major="4" minor="2">
  <header>
    ....
    <field name="DeliverToCompID" required="Y"/>

Comment: Thanks @EduardoSanchez-Ros, but this didn't help because when I added <field name="DeliverToCompID" required="Y"/> in the header then both the apps aren't able to establish the connection, as receiver is expecting tag128 even in the logon message also, but I am only sending /want to send tag128 in NewOrderSingle Message only.```        
                                                  <20221112-05:04:23, FIX.4.2:FIXIMULATOR->BANZAI, event> (Tried to send a reject while not logged on: Required tag missing (field 128)
quickfix.SessionException: Tried to send a reject while not log

Comment: You can leave the standard header for admin messages and define your own header for app messages

Comment: Thank You @EduardoSanchez-Ros I tried defining header for app messages this way,   <message name="NewOrderSingle" msgtype="D" msgcat="app">
    <header>
        <field name="DeliverToCompID" required="Y"/>
    </header> ,   But now it is not rejecting the messages if TAG128  is not present. Is is the correct way to define the header for application messages.